# Losing column widths when printing HTML table

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm have a page that will be used (and hence styled) only for printing. When I view the page in the browser the column width are as I set them:

```
<table>
<col width="20%">
<col width="25%">
<col width="5%">
<col width="10%">
<col width="17%">
<col width="15%">
<col width="8%">
<thead>
      header columns
</thead>
<tbody>
      columns
</tbody>
</table>
```

However, when I print the page the columns are all identical widths. Am I able to set columns as percentages (or at all) when printing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using `<table style="table-layout: fixed;">`.

This will force the table to use the specified widths.

Historically widths on table columns have always been more of a "suggestion" to the browser, and act more like a `min-width` to some extent. Setting `table-layout: fixed` will circumvent that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix my printing issue. Column widths work great on-screen, but printing still equalizes all the column widths. Is this just something I'll have to deal with?

Comment: Hmm... it may be an issue with your printer driver, or other printer-related settings. Everything seems to work fine for me when I try the above.

Comment: I am currently experiencing this issue. Did this actually solve the problem?

Comment: I have the same problem in Chromium based browsers when printing to PDF

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following with printouts:

```
document.getElementById("ColID").style.visibility="collapse"; 
document.getElementById("ColID").style.display="none"; 
document.getElementById("ColID").style.width="0px"; 
document.getElementById("ColID").style.width=0;

<TABLE BORDER="1">
<TABLE BORDER="1" STYLE="table-layout: fixed;">
<TABLE BORDER="1" STYLE="table-layout: auto;">
```

All work with the screen, none with any printer drive, with a Chromium based browser.

Works with FireFox, Internet Explorer and old versions of Edge using Trident.